# How do you store an UInt64 in CoreData?

Tags: swift, string, xcode, core-data, uint64

My understanding is that a UInt64 can be any value from: 0 to 18446744073709551615

I need to save a UInt64 identifier to CoreData, however the values I see are:

[image]

I initially tried Integer 64 but now I am understanding that has a range of: -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807

Do developers usually store an UInt64 as a String and do conversions between the two types?  Is this the best practice?

Comment: It would be a waste to store it as a string. You would need 20 bytes instead of 8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can (losslessly) convert between `UInt64` and `Int64`:

```
// Set:
obj.int64Property = Int64(bitPattern: uint64Value)

// Get:
let uint64Value = UInt64(bitPattern: obj.int64Property)
```

You can define `uint64Value` as a computed property of the managed object class to automate the conversion:

```
@objc(MyEntity)
public class MyEntity: NSManagedObject {
    
    public var uint64Property: UInt64 {
        get {
            return UInt64(bitPattern: int64Property)
        }
        set {
            int64Property = Int64(bitPattern: newValue)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Should this be done also for UInt16s and UInt32s? Do you have any idea? I'm checking if I should proof my coredata code.

Comment: @trusk: You *can* do it, but it would be easier to use a Core Data value type which is sufficiently large for the unsigned integer values: "Integer 32" for UInt16 and "Integer 64" for UInt32.

Comment: thanks for the reply! Do you have any more documentation or recommended materials to read some more about this?

Comment: @trusk: No, I don't.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer by `Martin R` will work.

However it appears that this is part of the default implementation of `@NSManaged` properties by Apple.

I tested it like so:

1. I created a new Xcode project with Core Data and made a single Entity called `Hello`.
2. It has a single attribute called `short` which is saved as an `Integer 16`.
3. Marked Codegen as `Manual/None`
4. Created the manual class file for `Hello` as follows:

```
class Hello: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var short : UInt16
}
```

You'll notice that I've typed it as an unsigned `UInt16`.

In my AppDelegate:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Get Context
        let context = self.persistentContainer.viewContext

        // Create Test Objects
        let hello1 = Hello(entity: Hello.entity(), insertInto: context)
        hello1.short = 255
        let hello2 = Hello(entity: Hello.entity(), insertInto: context)
        hello2.short = 266 // Should overflow Int16
        let hello3 = Hello(entity: Hello.entity(), insertInto: context)
        hello3.short = 65535 // Should overflow Int16 by a lot

        // Save them to the database
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        
        // Fetch the save objects
        let fetch = NSFetchRequest<Hello>(entityName: "Hello")
        if let results = try? context.fetch(fetch) {
            for result in results {
                print(result.short)
            }
        }
    }
```

This prints out the following:

```
255
266
65535
```

Which I imagine is what someone would want from saving unsigned ints in Core Data.

Comment: This works as expected for me. It seems the **Integer 64** type can be used as signed or unsigned 64-bit integers